# How to clone GCP Cloud Source Repositories in AWS instance

Tags: google-cloud-source-repos

I would like to clone GCP "Cloud Source Repositories" in AWS instance using GCP service account(IAM). I wanted to close using "git clone" command. Please let me know how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the find the official documetation [Cloning a repository](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/cloning-repositories).

You can clone using SSH authentication, Google Cloud SDK or Manually generated credentials.

I was able to clone the Cloud Source Repo to AWS:

1. I generate the ssh keys:

   ```
   ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "user@support.com"
   ```
2. I register a public key [link](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/authentication?authuser=1#generating_a_key_pair).
3. I cloned the repo:

   ```
    git clone ssh://useri@support.com@source.developers.google.com:2022/p/project/r/test
   ```

Comment: I already read this official documentation. "git clone" command won't work with "Service Account". We have to use google cloud SDK command like below

gcloud source repos clone flux --project=<projectname>

Comment: Why would you need a service account? Do you want to have some cloud function that will perform this task or do you want to clone from AWS instance?